# Why is this CSS grid overflowing?

Tags: css

Why is this grid bigger than it's container? In my mathematical calculations `45+20+35` should equal to 100%. The problem does not occur when fractions are used.

What is causing the overflowing issue when using percentages? Is it the gap property being added? How should one account for that when using percentages?

```css
body {
  width: 100%;    
}

.photo-grid {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 45% 20% 35%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
  gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas: "column-1 column-2 column-3" "column-1 column-2 column-3";
}

.column-1 {
  grid-area: column-1;
}

.photo-1 {
  height: calc(80% - 30px);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.column-2 {
  grid-area: column-2;
}

.photo-2 {
  height: 100%;
}

.column-3 {
  grid-area: column-3;
}

.photo-3 {
  height: calc(50% - 15px);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.photo-4 {
  height: calc(50% - 15px);
}

.textblock {
  background: salmon;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-grid">
  <div class="column-1">
    <div class="photo-1">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="Team na ziplinen" loading="lazy" />
    </div>
    <div class="textblock">
      <div>
        <p class="bold">Textblock</p>
        <p>Subtext</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-2">
    <div class="photo-2">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" loading="lazy" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column-3">
    <div class="photo-3">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" loading="lazy" />
    </div>
    <div class="photo-4">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" loading="lazy" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) the percentage is a value relative to the inline size of the grid container so the gap is added to this value.

Comment: more specifically (better than copying the documentation): Percentages are values absolute to the parent element. As such neither gap, padding (of parent element) not margin are taken into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, it's because of the gap.

You can use fraction units to get rid of this behavior:

grid-template-columns: 4.5fr 2fr 3.5fr;

If you still want to use percentages, you have to calculate the available room according to your set gap ( i edited this answer and applied an example in the snippet)

Additionally, instead of using containers with classes, you can access the grid-cells using css child-selectors like nth-child or nth-of type to style them and position them by using grid-column and grid-row.

I simplified your source for this example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.photo-grid {
  margin: 50px 0;
  height: 300px;
  display: grid;
  gap: 30px;
  /*
   * easy Solution: grid-template-columns: 4.5fr 2fr 3.5fr;
   */
  /*
   * complex solution: use calc() to calculate the available space per column excluding gaps
   * (available space = gap * (columnCount - 1) / columnCount
   */
  --gapSpace: calc((30px * 2) / 3);
  grid-template-columns: calc(45% - var(--gapSpace)) calc(20% - var(--gapSpace)) calc(35% - var(--gapSpace));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.photo-grid img:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column: 2 / 3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.textblock {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 2/3;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: salmon;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-grid">

  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" loading="lazy" />

  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" loading="lazy" />

  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" loading="lazy" />

  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1568605117036-5fe5e7bab0b7?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" loading="lazy" />

  <div class="textblock">
    <p class="bold">Textblock</p>
    <p>Subtext</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: correct. A main reason why you should sue fraction instead of percent. Percentage is absolute to the parents width/height. fraction takes the remaining space (after gap and padding) and fractures that remaining into equal fractions in the sum of the total fractions.

Comment: Thanks, so use fractions preferably, as the % appears to overcomplicate it unnecessarily. But this unexpectedly created an issue with my media query, which did work with %. I hide the middle column on mobile by changing the grid properties to: `grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;   grid-template-areas:  "column-1 column-3" "column-1 column-3";`but this breaks the whole grid. Do you have any tips on removing a column on certain resolutions?

Comment: Do you want to completely get rid of the second column or just break the layout so it displays differently?

Comment: @davidgiesemann Remove it completely, found that I have to add `display: none` to the column-2. Something that wasn't required with % for some reason. Wonder why 

Comment: I think: 
As you are limiting the grid-rows to a count of 2, and assigned all grid areas to the number of existing grid-cells, the column-2-content could only have been displayed in row 3, which does not exist.